# Bootstrap navigation hamburger dropdown extends too far to the left

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

[Image of the dropdown covering the next section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqmmR.png)

I have a mobile view dropdown navigation menu for my Bootstrap 3 styled site.  The issue is that the dropdown covers 90% of the width of the screen and that cuts off the top of my first section.  I would prefer to have the dropdown width limited to a small amount larger than its contents.

So far I managed to get the nav li to text align on the left.  That is good for me. Now I want to decrease the container width so that it no longer covers my image and stays out of the way on the left.

I apologize that my snippet doesn't work well, but the image shows exactly what I am seeing. Thanks

```css
*,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

nav {
  max-width: 100vw !important;
}

nav .container {
  margin-right: 1vmax;
  margin-left: 15vmax !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  #navbar ul {
    text-align: end !important;
  }
  #navbar ul li {
    /* width: 4vmax !important; */
  }
}

#navbar li a {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.navbar-default {
  background: white;
  border: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
}

.nav-logo {
  font-size: 2.8rem !important;
  letter-spacing: .11vw;
  font-family: 'PierSans';
  color: rgb(56, 56, 56);
}

.nav-brand {
  font-size: 2.8rem !important;
  letter-spacing: .06vw;
  color: rgb(56, 56, 56);
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Roboto', "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Google Home</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:300,400,500,600,700%7CRoboto%7CJosefin+Sans:100,300,400,500" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,800;1,400;1,600;1,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only ml-auto">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <span class="nav-logo">Google</span>
          <span class="nav-brand">Home</span>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse col-sm-3">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <!--"navbar-right 'or left'" moves this component in that direction-->
          <li><a href="#showcase">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#info1">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>


  <section id="showcase">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="showcase-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.jp/150x50.png">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="showcase-right">
            <h1>Hands-free help from the Google Assistant</h1>
            <p>Google Home voice-activated speaker.consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
            </p>
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-md showcase-btn">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256- 
 [enter image description here][1]DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoFc0.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try making `nav.navbar` background transparent and apply `background-color` to `#navbar ul li`

Here is your updated code:

HTML(Nothing changed):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only ml-auto">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          <span class="nav-logo">Google</span>
          <span class="nav-brand">Home</span>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse col-sm-3">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <!--"navbar-right 'or left'" moves this component in that direction-->
          <li><a href="#showcase">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#info1">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>


  <section id="showcase">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="showcase-left">
            <img src="http://placehold.jp/150x50.png">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
          <div class="showcase-right">
            <h1>Hands-free help from the Google Assistant</h1>
            <p>Google Home voice-activated speaker.consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
            </p>
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-md showcase-btn">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

CSS:

```
*,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 10px;
}

body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

nav {
  width: 100%;
/*   max-width: 100vw !important; */
}

nav .container {
/*   margin-right: 1vmax; */
/*   margin-left: 15vmax !important; */
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  nav.navbar{
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
  }
  
  #navbar ul {
    float: right !important;
    text-align: right !important;
  }
  #navbar ul li {
    /* width: 4vmax !important; */
    width: 45vw;
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
  }
  
  .navbar-header{
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
  }
  
  .navbar-brand{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 80%;
  }
  
}

#navbar li a {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
}

.navbar-default {
  background: white;
  border: 0;
  font-family: 'Poppins';
}

.nav-logo {
  font-size: 2.8rem !important;
  letter-spacing: .11vw;
  font-family: 'PierSans';
  color: rgb(56, 56, 56);
}

.nav-brand {
  font-size: 2.8rem !important;
  letter-spacing: .06vw;
  color: rgb(56, 56, 56);
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Roboto', "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/debrajr/pen/MWybvdp

Cheers!